# Count the order of the last digit of a number in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, logic, digits

Hy everybody, 
I'm trying to write a program with Python that tells me the order of the last digit of a number: for example if the number is 230 then the answer is 1, for 0.104 it is 0.001, for 1.0 it is 0.1 and so on... I've tried to write something but it does strange things for float numbers: it is approximately right for numbers that do not end with 0, and it is wrong for those ending with 0. This is what I wrote:

```
def digit(x):
if (x-int(x))==0:
    return 1
else:
    return 0.1*digit(x*10)
```

Thanks to anybody who will answer.

Comment: I think to process it as a string would be easier

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`decimal.Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) to obtain the amount of decimal places, and compute the order of the last digit as `1e^x`, `x` can be obtained through the `exponent` attribute of the named tuple returned by `decimal.Decimal.as_tuple()`:

```
import decimal

def order_last_digit(d):
    dec = decimal.Decimal(str(d))
    return 10**dec.as_tuple().exponent
```

---

```
order_last_digit(230) #10^0=1
# 1

order_last_digit(0.104) #10^-3
# 0.001

order_last_digit(1.0)
# 0.1
```

Comment: Thaks a lot! It looks also so easy

Answer (score 0):

it seems the first part of your code works right so i didn't touch it.

```
def digit(x):
  if (x-int(x))==0:
    return 1
  else:
    return '0.'+''.join(['0' for i in str(x).split('.')[1][0:-1]]+['1'])
```

Comment: Thanks also to you. But I'd like to understand what that code means... How can I do this?